# Facebook game development, University project, Front end woes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, flash, html

I have been requested to make a port of an iOS game for Facebook.
The game itself is fairly simple, it is a puzzle game using a 2d array for a grid with XML passed from a server for loading objects onto the the grid, to create levels.
The game will ask questions at stages which will be passed to my server and stored for research purposes.

Some questions for those with experience.
**What front-end options do I have with Facebook?**

I have looked into both Flash and HTML5/js both of which i have little to no experience in (I'm experienced in Java/C#/Ruby + Rails).
Javascript seems like a nightmare from what I have read, even looking into javascript game engines, but at least it is free. 
My backend will most likely be rails for handling server logic.

Summary(because I ramble too much)

-**Is javascript for programming games really a problem for simple games on Facebook?**

-**Are js game engines worth using? Does anyone have any experience with them?**

**-Would prevention of cheating be possible with a js/rails game, do server side checks work?**

-**Are there any alternatives for a front end for someone with C#/Java/Ruby background?**
I've never seen any Unity or Java apps on Facebook(I don't use it much) and I don't know if the licensing will be an issue for this research project.

Any input from those experienced would be greatly appreciated, I feel a bit lost with all the potential options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to the summary

**-No, it is not a problem.**
It brings with it certain challenges that will need to be understood, but it is a mature platform with loads of online documentation

**-Definitely, but maybe not even necessary.** It doesn't sound like your game is that complex, so you can probably feel comfortable trying any engine and seeing where it takes you. You may be more in need of data frameworks to deal with synchronization and management of state. I can't really recommend much without knowing more.

**-Yep, preventing cheating is definitely possible.** If banks can prevent arbitrary money exchange or invalid transactions, you can prevent cheating in a facebook game. You'll have to validate a lot on the server side, but that's par for the course.

**-Besides flash, no.** It's a javascript world out there. Flash has a lot of potential for serious games in the future, but if I were new to both I would probably bet more on JavaScript for the various other benefits it brings to the table (general web interaction, server side programming, etc)

If you are unconvinced of what JavaScript is capable of, head over to a site like [chrome experiments](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/) to see what people are squeezing out of browsers nowadays.

Comment: Flash had potential for serious games in the past. The future is all HTML5.

Comment: Thanks for the input, gives me some perspective I needed.